# Como verificar se um código contém 3 letras e 4 números nesta ordem?

Tags: c, validação

Estou atribuindo o retorno da função verifica código a uma flag. A ideia é fazer com que o flag dispare o loop, se o código estiver incorreto

```
char *leValidaCodigoAviao(char *msg, char *msgErro){
    char *pNome=0, nome[MAX];
    strcpy(nome, "");
    int stringTam=0, flag=1, verificador=0;

    do{
        printf("%s", msg);
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%[^\n]s", nome);

        if(strlen(nome)==0){
            printf("%s", msgErro);
            flag=0;
        }else if(strlen(nome)<COD_ID || strlen(nome)>COD_ID){
            flag=0;

        }else{

            verificador = verificaCodigo(nome);
            printf("%d", verificador);
            flag = verificador;
        }


    }while(!flag);
    system("cls");
    getch();
    return pNome = nome;
}
int verificaCodigo(char nome[]){
    int i, flag=1;


    for(i=0;i<COD_ID;i++){
        if(i<3){
            if(!isalpha(nome[i])){
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
        }else{
            if(!isdigit(nome[i])){
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return flag;
}
```

Comment: Era para ele entrar no loop apenas se o código estivesse incorreto. Por exemplo, ma10340 -> 3143mdafd ->  mar103b.  Caso contrário, ele sai do loop. Eu já mudei os valores das flags, mas não mudou nada.

Comment: Mas tem de devolver `0` se estiver errado e `1` se estiver certo, assumindo que certo é 3 letras seguidas de 4 numeros é isso ?

Comment: Sim. Eu testei aqui, mas por alguma razão continua dando erro.

Comment: Consegui. Era um problema com o tamanho da string. Valeu, Isac! Ajudou muito, parceiro!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da forma que a sua função `verificaCodigo` está escrita, é mais fácil trocar a atribuição que tem nos `ifs` para fazer o que pretende. Assim cada vez que vê que uma letra ou digito não está no local certo, coloca a `flag` a `0` em vez de `1` e termina o `for`:

```
int verificaCodigo(char nome[]){
    int i, flag=1;

    for(i=0;i<COD_ID;i++){
        if(i<3){
            if(!isalpha(nome[i])){
                flag=0; //0 em vez de 1
                break;
            }
        }else{
            if(!isdigit(nome[i])){
                flag=0; //0 em vez de 1
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return flag;
}
```

Testes:

```
printf("%d\n", verificaCodigo("ABC1234")); //1
printf("%d\n", verificaCodigo("1BC1234")); //0
printf("%d\n", verificaCodigo("AB11234")); //0
printf("%d\n", verificaCodigo("QQQ9999")); //1
printf("%d\n", verificaCodigo("123ABCD")); //0
printf("%d\n", verificaCodigo("abc1234")); //1
printf("%d\n", verificaCodigo("aBc9999")); //1
printf("%d\n", verificaCodigo("a0b1234")); //0
```

[Veja no Ideone](https://ideone.com/38qIAT)

Da forma que tinha a iniciar a `flag` em `1` e colocar `1` dentro do `if` não faria sentido pois estava a colocar o valor que já lá tinha, e não colocava `0` em nenhuma situação.